# XSL converting to an enum

Tags: java, xslt, enums

I'm new to XSL and struggling a bit with converting a anomalous value to a known enum in a JAXB-annotated class.  I have an enum defined as:

```
@XmlType( name = "accountGroup" )
@XmlEnum
public enum AccountGroup
{
    SOLD_TO, SHIP_TO, BILL_TO;

    public static AccountGroup fromValue( String v )
    {
        return valueOf( v );
    }

    public String value()
    {
        return name();
    }
}
```

An instance of this enum is in my target class as accountGroup.

When one of those enum values is in the source XML, everything is fine.  For example, one system passes in:

```
<acctType>SOLD_TO</acctType>
```

The XSL for this input just takes this and converts it to the XML the java class expects and the value gets set in the enum.

```
<xsl:element name="accountGroup"><xsl:value-of select="acctType"/></xsl:element>
```

However, one system is passing in different values that I need to convert, so I'm using a different XSL template for those inputs.  The source value looks something like:

```
<rn4:displayValue>Z001, Sold-to party</rn4:displayValue>
```

I'm trying to convert this with something like:

```
<xsl:element name="accountGroup">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="substring-before(rn4:matched/rn4:kTOKD/rn4:displayValue,',')='Z001'">
      SOLD_TO
    </xsl:when>
  </xsl:choose>
</xsl:element>
```

I've tested that the substring resolves to Z001, but the enum value does not get set.

What do I need to do?

Comment: Provide input XML and desired output and what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of just "SOLD_TO" in the 4th line use the following:

```
<xsl:value-of select="string('SOLD_TO')"/>
```